# How to create default document types and metadata sets in Liferay 6?

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I want to create **my own default** document types and metadata sets in *Liferay 6.1.20 EE*.

Currently, Liferay implementation creates its own default document types and metadata sets, e.g. Contract, Online Training, etc., which are created in the class AddDefaultDocumentLibraryStructuresAction, which is called from the class AddDefaultDataAction, which is a startup action.

As stated in a [Liferay Forum post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/13038033), in case we want to turn off this creation process, we need to comment out the relevant lines in AddDefaultDataAction or we can add a **custom AddDefaultDataAction** in the application.startup.events **overriding** the default one.

Can this be done using a **hook** to override application.startup.events? And if yes, how can we override AddDefaultDataAction class, as it is a **portal-impl.jar** class and we don't have access to it from a hook? If not, should an **ext plugin** be used for this purpose? Or is there a more straight-forward way to implement my own default document types and metadata sets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the default configuration, found in `portal.properties`, there it says

```
#
# Application startup event that runs once for every web site instance of
# the portal that initializes.
#
application.startup.events=com.liferay.portal.events.AddDefaultDataAction,\
     com.liferay.portal.events.AppStartupAction,\
     com.liferay.portal.events.ChannelHubAppStartupAction
```

So you can remove the default `com.liferay.portal.events.AddDefaultDataAction` from this list by just stating the others in your `portal-ext.properties`:

```
application.startup.events=com.liferay.portal.events.AppStartupAction,\
     com.liferay.portal.events.ChannelHubAppStartupAction
```

If you want to do this for all new installations, you'll have to add this change before the first start of the instance. Or you should write an ext plugin that does this out-of-the-box. Why do you need an ext? A hook can only *add* another StartupAction, *not change* the existing ones. An ext *can change or remove* existing startup actions or override their code.

In an ext plugin you could also implement

```
application.startup.events=com.mariaioannidou.MyCustomAddDefaultDataAction,\
     com.liferay.portal.events.AppStartupAction,\
     com.liferay.portal.events.ChannelHubAppStartupAction
```

and implement `MyCustomAddDefaultDataAction` as doing the same that the default action does, sans creating the document types.

On the other hand, a hook could find all of the standard document types that you don't want, check that they are indeed unused, and then delete them. As you can see, `AddDefaultDataAction` does quite a bit more than just adding the document types, so you might want the rest of the code in the action to run.

Another alternative is to write an ext plugin that actually changes the implementation of `com.liferay.portal.events.AddDefaultDataAction`, but there you are again with an ext - if you don't deploy this in every installation before your first startup, you'll end up with the default content anyway and you might want to have some code to delete it automatically.

My personal recommendation would be with a hook, deleting the unneeded document types (if they're unused) - the reasons are:

1. Ease of deployment (hot-deployment possible),
2. if you don't deploy your plugin before the first run, you end up needing to delete the unwanted document types anyway,
3. maintainability: It's easier to maintain a hook than an ext plugin.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your detailed answer. I understood the pros and cons of the two solutions, it seems that the hook approach fits more to my case.

Comment: I'd hope that you're not creating a new system on 6.1 (which this question from 2013 is about) in 2024. If you have a new question: Please ask a new question - but make sure it's programming related if you do so on stackoverflow.